# NodeJS and Sequelize, findOne issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using NodeJS 10.15 and Sequelize 3.24.3 ([sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v3/)). 
I'm just trying to check if a picture is already uploaded (to the db) checking some values, but it seems it cannot execute the query (no error, no warning, nothing, it just doesn't go on, it seems blocked by something).

I'm using a transaction too (there are few inserts and update before and after this function), but it should work according to the documentation.

 This is the function

```
//Just getting tables from the db, it's working in other parts of the project
const models = require('../../models_newdb');

var filenameAlreadyPresent = function(insertInfo) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return models.ReportingPicture.findOne({
            transaction: insertInfo.transaction, 
            where: {
                InspectionGroup_ID: insertInfo.insertInfo.inspectionGroupID,
                Building_ID: insertInfo.insertInfo.buildingID,
                FileName: insertInfo.returnInfo.fileName
            }
        })
        .then(function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        })
        .catch(error => { return reject(error); });
    })
    .catch(error => { throw error; });
}
```

Inside `insertInfo` we can find all values we need (including transaction). An example is:

```
InspectionGroup_ID: 33291
Building_ID: 6731
FileName: 33291_FG22502GC1_1638882304007.jpg
```

Any suggestion?

UPDATE: this is a console.log of `insertInfo.transaction` (the 3 dot notation is to hide some project information for my client, dont want to share those, but they are for the project, nothing related to the transaction)

```
Transaction {
  sequelize:
   Sequelize {
     options:
      { dialect: 'mssql',
        dialectModulePath: null,
        host: '192.168.1.13',
        protocol: 'tcp',
        define: {},
        query: {},
        sync: {},
        timezone: 'Europe/Rome',
        logging: false,
        omitNull: false,
        native: false,
        replication: false,
        ssl: undefined,
        pool: [Object],
        quoteIdentifiers: true,
        hooks: {},
        retry: [Object],
        transactionType: 'DEFERRED',
        isolationLevel: 'REPEATABLE READ',
        databaseVersion: '15.0.2000',
        typeValidation: false,
        benchmark: false,
        server: '192.168.1.13',
        dialectOptions: [Object] },
     config: { ... },
     dialect:
      MssqlDialect {
        sequelize: [Circular],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        QueryGenerator: [Object] },
     models: { ... },
     modelManager: ModelManager { models: [Array], sequelize: [Circular] },
     connectionManager:
      ConnectionManager {
        sequelize: [Circular],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [MssqlDialect],
        versionPromise: null,
        dialectName: 'mssql',
        onProcessExit: [Function: bound ],
        lib: [Object],
        pool: [Pool] },
     importCache: { ... },
     test:
      { '$trackRunningQueries': false,
        '$runningQueries': 0,
        trackRunningQueries: [Function: trackRunningQueries],
        verifyNoRunningQueries: [Function: verifyNoRunningQueries] },
     queryInterface:
      QueryInterface { sequelize: [Circular], QueryGenerator: [Object] } },
  savepoints: [],
  options:
   { autocommit: true,
     type: 'DEFERRED',
     isolationLevel: 'REPEATABLE READ',
     readOnly: false },
  parent: undefined,
  id: 'fb84f7cbbc75cd637099',
  name: undefined,
  connection:
   ResourceLock {
     resource:
      Connection {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        config: [Object],
        reset: [Function: bound reset],
        socketClose: [Function: bound socketClose],
        socketEnd: [Function: bound socketEnd],
        socketConnect: [Function: bound socketConnect],
        socketError: [Function: bound socketError],
        requestTimeout: [Function: bound requestTimeout],
        connectTimeout: [Function: bound connectTimeout],
        debug: [Debug],
        tokenStreamParser: [Parser],
        inTransaction: true,
        transactionDescriptors: [Array],
        state: [Object],
        connectTimer:
         Timeout {
           _called: false,
           _idleTimeout: -1,
           _idlePrev: null,
           _idleNext: null,
           _idleStart: 3975,
           _onTimeout: null,
           _timerArgs: undefined,
           _repeat: null,
           _destroyed: false,
           [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 3275,
           [Symbol(triggerId)]: 3221 },
        lib: [Object],
        socket: [Socket],
        messageIo: [MessageIO],
        closed: false,
        messageBuffer:
         <Buffer 00 00 1a 00 06 01 00 20 00 01 02 00 21 00 01 03 00 22 00 00 04 00 22 00 01 ff 0f 00 07 d0 00 00 02 00 00>,
        routingData: undefined,
        loggedIn: true,
        isSqlBatch: false,
        request: undefined,
        requestTimer: undefined,
        resetConnectionOnNextRequest: false,
        procReturnStatusValue: undefined },
     previous:
      Promise [Object] {
        _bitField: 33554432,
        _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
        _rejectionHandler0: [Connection],
        _promise0: undefined,
        _receiver0: undefined },
     uuid: 'fb84f7cbbc75cd637099' } 
}
```

Logging what sequelize is going, it's saying:

```
Executing (3ab31913c0c08511f65b): ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
{ Error: rollback has been called on this transaction(3ab31913c0c08511f65b), you can no longer use it. (The rejected query is attached as the 'sql' property of this error)
    at Sequelize.query (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:823:17)
    at QueryInterface.select (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\sequelize\lib\query-interface.js:708:25)
    at Model.<anonymous> (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1398:32)
    at Model.tryCatcher (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (E:\Progetti\SINA\sios\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  sql:
   'SELECT [FileName], [InspectionGroup_ID], [Building_ID] FROM [ReportingPicture] AS [ReportingPicture] WHERE [ReportingPicture].[InspectionGroup_ID] = 33291 AND [ReportingPicture].[Building_ID] = 6731 AND [ReportingPicture].[FileName] = N\'33291_FG22501GG1_1638881644010.jpg\';' }
```

That's weird because uploading other different data (uploaded via json), it works fine...it always worked fine (the function was completed like 2 months ago and always worked fine until now).
How can I know what's causing the rollback?

Comment: Apart from Anatoly's answer that solves the never-resolving promise you make, run your app while having the environment variable `DEBUG` set to `*` (`DEBUG=* node app.js`). You're probably not `commit()`ting the transaction, possibly due to an unresolved promise. The debug output'll show you what point its reaching. This question needs more details.

Comment: I am committing the transaction. With other data (using json files) it works just fine, with this particular json is not (even when i checked the data and everything seems fine). It seems sequelize rollbacks the transaction

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure `insertInfo.transaction` stores the correct transaction then just remove the mix of `Promise` and `then/catch` because `findOne` already returns `Promise`:

```js
var filenameAlreadyPresent = function(insertInfo) {
     return models.ReportingPicture.findOne({
         transaction: insertInfo.transaction, 
         where: {
             InspectionGroup_ID: insertInfo.insertInfo.inspectionGroupID,
             Building_ID: insertInfo.insertInfo.buildingID,
             FileName: insertInfo.returnInfo.fileName
         }
     })
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work....i'm pretty sure inside insertInfo.transaction there's the transaction...i will update my answer with a console.log of that ( the 3 dot notation is to hide some project information for my client, dont want to share those, but they are for the project, nothing related to the transaction)

Comment: Then show code where you call `filenameAlreadyPresent`

Comment: it doesn't work without the promise...and the code where i call the function is a nested function, so it would be hard to post the whole code.
Curiously though, if i remove the `transaction: inserInfo.transaction` part, it works....the problem is next to this one i have a create sequelize, and i need the transaction

Comment: Edited again, with the sequelize situation

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work without promise`? Your code doesn't call `resolve`. `findOne` also return Promise so there will be no difference

Comment: I didn't add the `resolve` in the example, but I have it in the project function...the problem is not the resolve situation (that works), but the fact it doesnt even reach the `console.log(results)`...its like the sequelize doesn't even work

Comment: It seems other code caused ROLLBACK on this transaction as you can see in the error message that's why you didn't get to `resolve` handler